# tivoli Omnibus probe rules program generate multiple events

Tags: tivoli, probe

I am writing probe rules to generate events in Omnibus ObjectServer.

As I did all the works and set the parameters (such as @Summary, @Identifier, @Agent, ....) and then sent out the event record with genevent(DefaultOS,@Node,$myNode,@NodeAlias, .....) command to the ObjectServer, I saw two event alerts from my Netcool console instead of one.

I later on commented out all @ parameter settings, such as

> $myNode = "ABCDEF"
>
> # @Node = $myNode
>
> $myManager = "CaseManager"
>
> # @Manager = $myManager
>   ......

and then only one event will get created in the ObjectServer (by genevent() command).

My question is: At which point (by setting these @ parameter) will trigger
an event be created in ObjectServer? Why would I created two event records while I only sent one genevent() to ObjectServer?

I searched on IBM Tivoli web site but unfortunately I cannot find the answer I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

genevent is used to create an extra event from your incoming data. The original event is always processed and sent to the ObjectServer with more or less fields populated depending on your rules files unless you discard it. However if you don't set the minimum fields required to identify the event (e.g. the @Identifier field) and differentiate it from other events then you won't see the result as a separate event. This is bad practice - just discard it if you don't want it to be processed and sent.